# CrystalReportViewer Highlights Fields

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I have a .NET Windows application with a CrystalReportViewer on form. I load various reports into the viewer that were created in Crystal Reports 2008. When the user is previewing a report (an invoice), as they move their mouse around over the report each field on the report is highlighted by a thin red rounded corner box as around the **Nissan** box. Clicking a field leaves a black, dotted border around the field as around the **MAKE:** box

*<broken image link removed>*

Does anyone know how to disable this behavior? It is confusing because the users are expecting to be able to do something else once a field is highlighted or selected.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, but hope someone else can provide the answer.

Comment: I did finally manage to find a discussion where someone offered that Business Objects had told him it was not possible and that people wanted it to work that way, followed by a list of people who said they did not. The thread was a couple of years old so I had hoped something had changed as it seems to be stupid behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to disable this behavior. It is a feature, not a bug.

If they ever do disable this behavior, I'm sure it will be a checkbox in the Report Options section.

Comment: Yes, that's what their tech support was saying. I wasn't calling it a bug. I was questioning the usefulness of the feature. Also some people have used some back door / unsupported methods to get things to look / work more to their liking. That's what I was really hoping for since I had been through the report options a dozen times without luck.

Comment: I do have an update that just randomly came about from one of our customers today... I never used it for this, but PREVIOUS versions of the Viewer control would allow you to right click and COPY the text that was selected. This seems to be no longer possible in 2008. All that to say, that's one reason it highlights, but I agree, there should be a way to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes  it is possible, same thing happens to me but I overcome to this by setting 'Enable' Property to 'false' in 'Behavior' section of report viewer properties.